# Ruby on Rails flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have controller:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    flash[:notice] = "GoodNight"
  end
end
```

and helper:

```
module FlashesHelper
  FLASHES_CLASS ={alert: "danger", notice: "success", warning: "warning"}.freeze    
  def flash_class(key)
    FLASHES_CLASS.fetch(key.to_sym, key)
  end
  def user_facing_flashes
    flash.to_hash.slice(:notice, :alert, :warning)
  end
end
```

I'm confused that when I do:

```
flash.to_hash.slice(:notice, :alert, :warning)
```

it doesn't work but if I do:

```
flash.to_hash.slice("notice", "alert", "warning")
```

it works.

If I try something like this:

```
book = Hash.new
book[:matz] = "Ruby"
book.to_hash.slice(:matz) # => {:matz => "Ruby"}
book.to_hash.slice("matz") # => {}
```

Please tell me why.

Comment: You should pay a little bit more attention on your writing : it is unclear what you are asking, and your exemple look like it could be shorter (you don't need the controller / helper code IMHO)

Comment: @UlysseBN: no, I find that controller/helper code are necessary here to demonstrate the issue. It's not a question about hashes, it's a question about behaviour of flash. Ok, maybe not [entire] helper :)

Comment: So the unnecessary part would be the last one on hash

Comment: @UlysseBN: that one is useful too (although can be much prettified). It shows that hash works as expected. But not flash, which seemingly is a hash too. This is research effort, what we encourage. :)

Comment: @sawa:    on cleaning up that IRB mess. :)

Comment: See HashWithIndifferentAccess: https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/with_indifferent_access

Comment: I don't really see why you would do this in the first place. The whole point of the flash hash is pass messages to the user. Unless they are all user facing you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think that `flash` is a hash. It's not. It's a [`FlashHash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html). And its `[]=` method casts keys to strings.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb, line 153
def []=(k, v)
  k = k.to_s
  @discard.delete k
  @flashes[k] = v
end
```

That's how your `:notice` becomes `'notice'` (before it's stored anywhere).

Comment: Since `to_hash` is applies, I don't think `FlashHash` or whatever is relevant. It is just a hash.

Comment: @sawa: on the contrary, It being a `FlashHash` is super-relevant. It's what does the conversion.